# See mouse coordinates when I move it over the paraview image

Tags: paraview

I'm looking for a way to see the cursor position of a 2D plot in paraview (vtk), that is, see the coordinates of the mouse when I move it over the paraview image.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can hover over a point and it will show you the `x` and `y` values of the plot.

Comment: thanks @Cory its a great solution. But with your solution I only can se e coordinates of elements vertices, but I want to see the mouse coordinates instead of there no vertices (for example when I have no much elements)

Comment: Sorry, that feature is not currently available in ParaView.